# Azure RoR capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, azure, capistrano

all the instructions Azure: goo.gl/fGNhrp

during the deployment phase received an error:

```
C:\Users\Maksym\Project\blog_app>bundle exec cap production setup
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
DEBUG [39ea3015] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p451 ] as joo
j@j00j.cloudapp.net
DEBUG [39ea3015] Command: [ -d ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p451 ]
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as jooj@jooj.cloudapp.net: Authentication failed for user jooj@jooj.cloudapp.net

Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user jooj@jooj.cloudapp.net

Tasks: TOP => rbenv:validate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: https://github.com/J00J/blog_app

Comment: It is mean that `j00j` user doesn't have access to your `jooj.cloudapp.net` server. Check it.

Comment: Make sure `ssh jooj@jooj.cloudapp.net` actually works.